API Web Request using C# fails only in AWS EC2 Instance
I have a code (C# .NET Framework 4.8) that is trying to invoke an API to get some data and after that will do something with it:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/");
queryString = null;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(queryString); // hangs here
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    // Do something
}

This code works fine in my PC but when I try to run it (even as administrator) in a server (AWS EC2 t2.micro Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 64 bits) it hangs and, after a couple of minutes, fails:
   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Se canceló una tarea. en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       en Program1.<requestDeals>d__26.MoveNext() in...

Using Firefox in the server I request the API and it returned the data without issues. After some investigation I modified the code like this but still does not work:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    UseCookies = true,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/");
queryString = null;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    // Do something
}

I checked the firewall and the program is in the exception list, there is no antivirus or proxy or something else installed.
I don't understand why the program fails and Firefox works. What is Firefox doing that my program doesn't? You may be thinking some configuration or permissions issues, but why Firefox runs fine without those and my program doesn't?
Extra: a few minutes ago I tried to use the "curl https://google.com" tool but the program didn't work. It appears is not only my program.
